# How do I execute a command with an automated script on a remote machine in a golang CLI?

Tags: go, ssh

I'm researching ssh and the command to follow. How would I go about executing a shell command in an ssh server automatically via script with golang CLI? I need to write a golang CLI automated script that can SSH into a remote machine via this format: "ip username:password". For example I have a file named "logins.txt" lets say 400-500 ssh logins. I would like the script to execute a shell command while logging into 400-500 ssh servers automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/melbahja/goph `Start Connection With Password`  `Execute Bash Commands`